# Запрос mongoose должен забрать часть полей

Tags: node.js, mongoose

Запрос

```
Items.find({}).lean()
```

возвращает коллекцию итемов, содержащих id, name, comment.
Как мне составить запрос, чтобы я получил коллекцию итемов, содержащих только часть полей? Например только id и имя.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вернуть только некоторые поля в таком объекте возможно используя метод select:

```
Items.find({}).select({id: 1, name: 1}).lean();
```

В данном примере будет возвращен массив итемов, содержащих только id и name.

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Дополнил, спасибо за совет.